# How to load external library from local path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code importing list of external urls(http//....js)

```
for (const id in urls) {
  let tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.async = false;
  tag.src = urls[id];
  let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(tag);
}
```

But for security reasons, I copy&pasted the js file to local file, but dont know how to import it like I used to do.
Simply

> import "../lib/asmcrypto.js";

gives me thousands of errors saying 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load an ES6 file directly into browser. This code was likely not meant to be loaded the way you want, but to be transpiled first using Babel.

Comment: can you post one example of the file you are trying to import?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier For example, [this js](https://peculiarventures.github.io/pv-webcrypto-tests/src/asmcrypto.js). I copied and pasted everything into a new file called src/lib/asmcrypto.js. I want to load this js somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a browser, the most common way of loading your JS resource would be:

```
<script src="/lib/asmcrypto.js"></script>
```

If you're using Webpack at some level, like when you're project is on React or Angular or ...

```
import crypto from "../lib/asmcrypto.js";
```

It's important to understand that, it's usually the bundler *e.g. Webpack* that takes care of `import` and `export` in your project.

Comment: Is this code doing the same as loading resource?`import crypto from "../lib/asmcrypto.js";` I dont use 'crypto' anywhere in the code. I just want to load.

Comment: Shouldn't the `<script>` tag also have a `type` argument, [as described in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)? The file he is trying to import has export statements, so it is an ES6 module.

Comment: No crypto is just a name you choose. I just chose crypto, you can choose whatever best describes the module you're importing.

Comment: @Titulum If it's a module yes. But the file extension is `js` not `mjs`

Comment: Well, still I cannot import from local path. I get error  'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

Comment: @MasakiMinamide What exactly do you want to achieve?
If you want to get some JS code out of your main js file, and you're using vanilla browser js, just use `<script>` tag and forget about `import`.
If you're on React, Angular, Vue or any project that has WebPack, go for `import`.